# Why the log reported ID inconsistent when started a new instance with docker of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I directly copied the complete data directory from one instance, and then started a new instance with docker on another server of Apache IoTDB. The data directory is the one just copied, but the log prompts that the IDs are inconsistent.

The startup is successful, but there is no data. Is there a way to solve it?